# Finding sum of specific values of array in hash

Tags: ruby

Here is my array:

```
collection

=> [{:title=>"Movie A", :studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>10},

{:title=>"Movie B", :studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>30},

{:title=>"Movie C", :studio=>"Omega Films", :worldwide_gross=>30}]
```

My objective is the return the sum of each respective studio:

```
#=> :studio => "Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross => 40

#=> :studio => "Omega Films", :worldwide_gross => 30
```

So far I've come up with the following logic but it only returns the sum of all studios in one lump sum:

```
gross_result = collection.sum {|h| h[:worldwide_gross]}
result #=> 70
```

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Instead of showing us the contents of `collection`, provide the code that defines `collection` then shows what you're trying to do with it. That way we're able to copy/paste the code and use it immediately. 'Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) then sum as you already did:

```
collection.group_by { |h| h[:studio] }.transform_values { |v| v.sum{ |h| h[:worldwide_gross] } }
#=> {"Alpha Films"=>40, "Omega Films"=>30}
```

Where `group_by` returns:

```
collection.group_by { |h| h[:studio] }
#=> {"Alpha Films"=>[{:title=>"Movie A", :studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>10}, {:title=>"Movie B", :studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>30}], "Omega Films"=>[{:title=>"Movie C", :studio=>"Omega Films", :worldwide_gross=>30}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution first creates a hash whose keys are the unique values of `g[:studio]` over all hashes `g` in `collection`, and whose values are the totals of `g[:worldwide_gross]` over all `g` for the given key. That hash is then converted to the desired hash.

```
collection.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|  
  h[g[:studio]] += g[:worldwide_gross]
end.map { |k,v| { studio: k, worldwide_gross: v } }
  #=> [{:studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>40},
  #    {:studio=>"Omega Films", :worldwide_gross=>30}]
```

The two steps are as follows.

```
h = collection.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |g,h|
  h[g[:studio]] += g[:worldwide_gross]
end
  #=> {"Alpha Films"=>40, "Omega Films"=>30} 
h.map { |k,v| { studio: k, worldwide_gross: v } }
  #=> [{:studio=>"Alpha Films", :worldwide_gross=>40},
  #    {:studio=>"Omega Films", :worldwide_gross=>30}]
```

The calculation of `h` (sometimes called a *counting hash*) employs the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) that defines a *default value* (here zero) that is the value returned by `h[k]` for a hash `h` so-defined when `h` does not have a key `k`. It is equivalent to the following.

```
h = collection.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h[g[:studio]] = (h[g[:studio]] || 0) + g[:worldwide_gross]
end
```

If `h` does not have a key `g[:studio]` then `h[g[:studio]]  #=> nil`, so `h[g[:studio]] || 0 #=> 0`. If `h` has a key `g[:studio]` (whose value is not `nil` or `false`) then `h[g[:studio]] || 0 #=> h[g[:studio]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce method

```
result = a.group_by { |h| h[:studio] }.values.map do |arr|
  arr.reduce do |h1, h2|
    h1.merge(h2) do |k, v1, v2|
      k.eql?(:worldwide_gross) ? (v1 + v2) : v1
    end
  end
end
```

p result

```
[{:partner_name=>"company 1", :partner_id=>787, :value=>3}, {:partner_name=>"company 2", :partner_id=>768, :value=>1}, {:partner_name=>"company 3", :partner_id=>769, :value=>1}]
```